# Google places api only include results that have postal_code

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Is there a way of having a search input where a user can type a city name and it only returns results that have a postal code?
For this particular situation we don't want the user to enter the full address.
The fields we need are City, Postal code and Country.
I know we can limit the results by setting the flag types=(cities) but when searching for city name the first results never include the postal_code.
I though of doing a reverse lookup with the provided city coordinates but some cities have more than one postal codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to filter places from Place Autocomplete predictions on postal codes only.

However, there is an open feature request in Google's Issue Tracker which I suggest starring to increase visibility and subscribe to future notifications:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067

Hope this helps!